# Logstash MongoDB Output plugin 3.1.7 error

Tags: mongodb, plugins, output, logstash

I am not able to connect to MongoDB Atlas with below error.Using plugin version 3.1.7.

> *[WARN ][logstash.outputs.mongodb ][main] MONGODB | Failed to handshake with : 27017 ArgumentError: wrong number of
> arguments (given 2, expected 1)*
>
> [*WARN ][logstash.outputs.mongodb ][main] MONGODB | Error checking
> :27017: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given
> 2, expected 1)*

Mongodb url is *"mongodb+srv://username:password@clustername.mongodb.net/dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority"*

I see, the version has [fix](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-mongodb/commit/f6d3a73735d0871bc765afd2a8cff00152e36e73) 1 for the same issue. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Have you used [logstash-plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/working-with-plugins.html#listing-plugins) to confirm that you have version 3.1.7 of the plugin or later?

Comment: Yes. It is 3.1.7. logstash-output-mongodb (3.1.7)

Comment: I just installed the plugin with bin/logstash-plugin install. Do I need gem install too?

Comment: Running logstash-plugin to install it should be enough.

Comment: Thanks Badger. Trying to find out any success story with latest plugin version around on the web, but no luck, and I'm still getting the issue. Tried with local host mongo instance too.